# Inject custom steps in a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

Assume I have the following PS Script **myscript.ps1**:

```
param(
  [string]$ID
)

Write-Host "Step 1 $ID"
Write-Host "Step 2 $ID"
# Inject some custom step here
Write-Host "Step 3 $ID"
```

That I call from another PS script with

```
$ [path]\myscript.ps1 -ID 001
$ [path]\myscript.ps1 -ID 002
$ [path]\myscript.ps1 -ID 003
```

Now when I run the last call:

```
$ [path]\myscript.ps1 -ID 003
```

I would like to trigger some custom behavior/steps just after:

```
Write-Host "Step 2 $ID"
```

in **myscript.ps1**. I considered this:

```
$ [path]\myscript.ps1 -ID 001
$ [path]\myscript.ps1 -ID 002
$ [path]\myscript.ps1 -ID 003 -customScript "[path]\custom.ps1"
```

and then update **myscript.ps1** to:

```
param(
  [string]$ID,
  [string]$custom=""
)

Write-Host "Step 1 $ID"
Write-Host "Step 2 $ID"
if($custom) {
    & $custom
}
# Inject some custom step here
Write-Host "Step 3 $ID"
```

Maybe there are some more elegant way of doing this?

I have looked at:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/06/11/powershell-eventing-quickstart.aspx

but it does not really seem to fit the purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass custom [ScriptBlock](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847893.aspx) and execute it:

```
param(
  [string]$ID,
  [scriptblock]$custom
)

Write-Host "Step 1 $ID"
Write-Host "Step 2 $ID"

# Inject some custom step here
if($custom){. $custom}

Write-Host "Step 3 $ID"
```

Example:

```
$ [path]\myscript.ps1 -ID 001
$ [path]\myscript.ps1 -ID 002
$ [path]\myscript.ps1 -ID 003 -custom {Write-Host "I'm a custom scriptblock!"}
```

More about executing scriptblocks:

- [Some observations about Powershell script blocks](https://mjolinor.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/some-observations-about-powershell-script-blocks/).

Comment: Whether that's more elegant than passing the path to a custom script file is debatable, though.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Scriptblock can run custom scipt, so it's more versatile IMO.

Comment: A custom script can run custom scriptblock as well. Both approaches are equivelent in terms of functionality.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Scriptblocks are easier to build on the fly then files. Saves you one intermediate step and disk I/O. Of course, it depends on a amount of code to execute - after some threshold creating a full-fledged script is more preferable. But for the short snippets I'd use a scriptblock.